# How do I put everything in onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: android, kotlin

My activity uses Glide and PhotoView. I do not understand how it is possible to make the activity retain its state when exiting the application.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val bt_js = findViewById<View>(R.id.bt_js)
        val bt_is = findViewById<View>(R.id.bt_is)
        val url_js = "https://fikiwiki.com/uploads/posts/2022-02/1644855597_24-fikiwiki-com-p-kartinki-khd-kachestva-25.jpg"
        val url_is = "https://mobimg.b-cdn.net/v3/fetch/f4/f4e488ef69ea10573c0ce9cfbaf08643.jpeg"
        val photoView = findViewById<PhotoView>(R.id.photo_view)
        bt_js.setOnClickListener {
            Glide.with(this)
                .load(url_js)
                .into(photoView)
        }
        bt_is.setOnClickListener {
            Glide.with(this)
                .load(url_is)
                .into(photoView)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to search for information, but everything is only for Java, or nothing is clear to me as a beginner

Comment: use MVVM . https://appdevnotes.com/android-viewmodel-tutorial-for-beginners-in-kotlin/

Comment: What state do you want to store specifically, i.e. what do you want the user to see after they reopen your application?

Comment: `How do I put everything in onSaveInstanceState?` Wrong question if you wanna save a state at exiting the app. OnSaveInstanceState() is useless then.

Comment: @Max The user click on the button. An image will appear. After restarting the application, the image remains in place (and the zoom is saved too, as the user selected before closing)

Comment: Saved instance state is for restoring details about the UI after your app is resumed from suspension, in the case where the OS may have torn down your Activity to save memory. Saved instance state is completely erased if the application is actually exited / restarted, so I think you're asking the wrong question. For information to survive the app restarting, you need to back it up to disk manually: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage It's up to you to decide which pieces need to be saved and how. It's situation dependent--no easy "save everything" option.

Comment: @Tenfour04 then can you tell me what you need to do to save everything after exiting the application?

Comment: I edited my last comment.

Comment: omg didn't think it was so difficult

Comment: @Tenfour04 I wrote the permission in the manifest. It turns out that then I need to somehow inform that I need to save everything to the storage?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about exactly.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm trying to figure out what needs to be written so that the application writes to disk. I'm looking on the internet, but they write about Int, String, etc., but this is not what I have. Or I don't understand something...

Comment: It depends on what you're writing and what storage solution you've chosen. Refer to the table in the link I posted to see if you even need permissions. You almost certainly do not need any permissions or to touch the manifest at all for this, because you don't need to save the files externally.